# Can not preview message in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app

Using last OS X Lion, I was using Mail.app, classic view, so there was always a preview for each message. This has now dissapeared, how can I solve this?

Comment: With classic view, you mean you use Preferences>Viewing>Use classic layout? The preview view may be minimized, is there a separator at the bottom of the window which you could drag? Could you add a screenshot of Mail.app?

Comment: yes!!! the separator was somehow hidden, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great it worked, I added an answer, take a look at it and accept it if you think it correctly describes how to solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: of course, don now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic view is the view set in Preferences>Viewing>Use classic layout:

[image]

In this view, the message preview area is located below the message list.

The view may be minimized:

[image]

Just drag the separator at the bottom of the window to show the message area.